# Is there a way to create a folder tree of all Shared Drives as an admin?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Google Drive is quite impressive for a web app, but it seems to be optimised for search, not spatial navigation so it's painfully slow for myself and colleagues trying to navigate, especially if we don't know exactly which file or folder we're looking for.

To help them out, I would like to create a "site map" of each Shared Drive, basically just a tree view so they can see the overall folder structure and jump straight to a specific folder, even if it's 5 or 6 folders deep. The tree might look something like this:

> [Shared Drive
> Name](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/shared_drive_id) (4
> files)
>
> - [Folder 1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder1_id) (0 files)
>
>   - [Folder 1a](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder1a_id) (12 files)
>   - [Folder 1b](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder1b_id) (13 files)
> - [Folder 2](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder2_id) (1 file)
> - [Folder 3](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder3_id) (3 files)
>
>   - [Folder 3a](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder3a_id) (12 files)
>   - [Folder 3b](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder3b_id) (9 files)
>   - [Folder 3c](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder3c_id) (15 files)
>   - [Folder 3d](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folder3d_id) (6 files)

I have a [working proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/matt17r/6b3095c9f7bc450d83b72c1d29c2dee4) that I was thinking I could run daily/nightly but it falls down on Shared drives that I don't have access to. I can list the drives as an admin, using `Drive.Drives.list({useDomainAdminAccess: true}).items;`, but I can't list the contents.

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `useDomainAdminAccess: true` on `Drive.Files.list`? Is there another workaround? I'm wondering if I need to first check if I have access to the drive... if I don't I could then:

- give myself view access to the Shared Drive
- create the file list
- remove my access again

I think it would work, it just feels like an ugly hack so I'm wondering if there's a better approach?

Comment: I have done something similar to that but it is painfully slow. As a result I never use it. But have you noticed that the is a little triangle just to the left of the folders.  Try clicking on them they do a pretty good and quick job of showing the tree structure and if you go to the same places regular try starring them and using the starred section.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample output situation you expect as an image?

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. I have used the disclosure triangles in the tree view in the left sidebar and it's definitely better than double-clicking through the main Grid or List views but it's still not great (still a little slow, very cramped, and no indication of file content until you click on a folder and wait for it to slowly load).

Comment: @Tanaike, I have added sample output of the script to show what I mean by a "site map" or tree view. It's at the [same URL](https://gist.github.com/matt17r/6b3095c9f7bc450d83b72c1d29c2dee4)

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw the link you provided. From the URL, in your goal, you want to export the file list as the markdown format? I apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Are all the users and files within your domain? If so, have you looked into [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) with [domain wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)? To use them from Apps Script you would need the [OAuth Library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2).